# Extract a particular string form a long string in php

Tags: php

I have this string "PAX 098-5503268037/ETAI/USD107.75/15MAY20/KTMVS31KL/10303171" and would like to extract the USD107.75.I have this function:

Here:

```
$str = PAX 098-5503268037/ETAI/USD107.75/15MAY20/KTMVS31KL/10303171;
$from = '/ETAI';
$to = '/';

    public function getStringBetween($str,$from,$to)
    {
        $sub = substr($str, strpos($str,$from)+strlen($from),strlen($str));
        return substr($sub,0,strpos($sub,$to));
    }
```

The function only return an empty string.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe explode by `/` and take 3rd element?

Answer (score 2):

If you do a bit of debugging...

```
public function getStringBetween($str,$from,$to)
{
    $sub = substr($str, strpos($str,$from)+strlen($from),strlen($str));
    echo $sub.PHP_EOL;
    return substr($sub,0,strpos($sub,$to));
}
```

you will see the interim output is

```
/USD107.75/15MAY20/KTMVS31KL/10303171
```

as you then look for the first `/` and extract up to that, that is the first character.

A simple solution to what you already have is to add `+1` in the start position...

```
public function getStringBetween($str,$from,$to)
{
    $sub = substr($str, strpos($str,$from)+strlen($from)+1,strlen($str));       
    return substr($sub,0,strpos($sub,$to));
}
```

Alternatively, you can as u_mulder indicated, `explode()` on / and then extract the part you are after...

```
echo explode("/", $str)[2];
```